# Installing extension from outside the Web Store via Google Workspace

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-workspace

I have developed an extension for my organisation and would like to deploy it to a select group of users. I have read all the documentation I could find on the matter, it seems limited, obviously Google would rather you used the store...Unless somesomeone can point out what I have missed, I will take that route.

The extension is currently hosted on our IIS server, accessible from the internet.

I have packaged the extension as a .crx and I have created an XML file with details for the APP ID and updatecheck URL etc. I have set the MIME type to be `application/x-chrome-extension` and I have checked and confirmed that the .crx file is not served with the "no sniff" header.

[image]

In Google Workspace admin, I have to add the ID and the URL. Getting the ID is simple enough, it is displayed during the development and packaging process. What isn't clear is what I should enter for the URL? Do I enter the path to the .crx file? To a directory containing the files? Is there a naming convention? I do not seem to be able to find this information.

[image]

I can see that the policy is applying, but the extension does not install. I assume this is because the URL or ID value is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: As a side note, I have noticed that whilst the policy is in place in Google Workspace, I am unable to load the extension in developer mode.